# getting the currently logged on user and the number of valid stored procedure in sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to find out if its possible to get the number of valid and invalid stored procedures in SQL. Also the currently logged on user and the current time

Comment: Invalid stored procedures? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you want local time, with or without timezone, or UTC? Just the time, or including date?

Comment: @jarlh without the date and it has to be UTC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I’m using Oracle DB. I know you can’t write Stored procedures on SQL but I think it’s possible to check the number of Invalid Stored procedures using SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the invalid objects use

```
SELECT *
FROM   dba_objects
WHERE  object_type IN ('PACKAGE'
                     , 'PACKAGE BODY'
                     , 'PROCEDURE'
                     , 'FUNCTION')
AND    status <> 'VALID';
```

OR

```
SELECT STATUS, COUNT(*)
FROM   dba_objects
WHERE  object_type IN ('PACKAGE'
                     , 'PACKAGE BODY'
                     , 'PROCEDURE'
                     , 'FUNCTION')
GROUP BY status
```

for just a count of the statuses.

You might need to tweak the list of object types depending on what you want and you may want to limit it by OWNER as well.

The following shows the current time and a few methods of getting the user (schema, OS and the user from 'client identifier').
I suggest you try it and see which one you actually want and/or have populated.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS current_NLS
     , TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP),'HH24:MI:SS') AS UTC_TIME
     , USER
     , SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER')
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'client_identifier'), '^[^:]*')
FROM   DUAL;
```